# Regular expression of $L = \{w \in \{0, 1\}^* \mid w \text{ does not contain $111$}\}$

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm trying to find regular expression of $L = \{w \in \{0, 1\}^* \mid w \text{ does not contain $111$}\}$. I think there are many information about regular expression that does not contain the substring $110$. but I think $111$ is more difficult to find. can anybody help?

Comment: Since you have found examples of regular expressions for avoiding `110`, which attempts have you made to adapt their methods to `111`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the set of strings over {a, b} that do not contain the substring aaa](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933937/finding-the-set-of-strings-over-a-b-that-do-not-contain-the-substring-aaa)

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere you see a $1$ in this string, it is either

- At the end,
- followed by a $0$, or
- followed by $10$.

Therefore, strings in this language are built out of copies of $0$, $10$, and $110$, possibly with an extra $1$ at the end. Can you use this to build an RE?

Comment: I tried. Is it 1?(0+10)*1?  ?

Comment: Almost. With what you have now, there is no way to get strings containing more than one instance of 110.

Comment: I cannot come up with this... can you please help?

Comment: You want to allow arbitrarily many instances of $110$, so you should put $110$ within the $(\quad )^*$.@Junghoon

Comment: then 1?(0+10+110)1? I think this works!

Comment: Aaaaaaalmost! The only problem is the 1? at the beginning, as this can combine with 110 to make 1110. Get rid of that and you’re golden

Answer (score 0):

Use the Arden's theorem.

Answer: (0+10+110)*(€+1+11)
This is probably the minimal regexp. Or maybe it can get minimised.

Details.

DFA Delta moves. Or transitions.

Qo = {A} initial state.
N = {A, B, C, D(dead state) } All states

d(A, 0) = A
d(A, 1) = B

d(B, 0) = A
d(B, 1) = C

d(C, 0) = A
d(C, 1) = D

A=A0+B0+C0
B=A1
C=B1
D=C1

Solve for A then B then C.

Note if R = RP + Q
Then,   R = QP* Arden's theorem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).