# Regular expression without subword 000

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

what is the regular expression for the language above {0,1} that does not contain the subword 000?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: The only hint I could think of: a regular expression for the language on $\{0,1\}$ that does not contain the subword $00$ is $(0+1+10)(1+10)*$. If you can understand why this regex works, then you should be able to find one for your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the set of strings over {a, b} that do not contain the substring aaa](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933937/finding-the-set-of-strings-over-a-b-that-do-not-contain-the-substring-aaa)

Comment: Yes it does! thank you!